# Why cannot php-mongo run on php 5.6 and ubuntu 16.4?

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

I installed php 5.6 from [ondrej](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu) repo and php-mongo extension but module cannot be loaded. I faced the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/mongo.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/mongo.so: undefined symbol: sk_value in Unknown on line 0
```

I not want to use `php-mongodb` extension.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: At a guess, incompatible versions i.e. That mongo wont run with that PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install -f php-pear php5.6-dev
sudo pecl install mongo
```